# PHP Redirect Without Modifying Headers

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I have a PHP script that is redirecting the user via some code like:

`header ('Location: http://someurl/somepage.php');`

Then in somepage.php I am trying to access `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to determine where the page request has come from.  I find that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is empty when a page is called using the header location method.

Is there an alternative method that I can use to redirect the user so that I can still use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in the target page.

Answer (score 6):

One thing you could try: instead of sending the `Location` header, send back an HTML page with the tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://someurl/somepage.php">
```

in the `<head>` section. I'm not sure if it would fix your problem, though... it really depends on how the browser behaves. The value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` comes from the `Referer` request header which the browser is free to send or not send, at its discretion.

Something else you could do is

```
header("Location: http://someurl/somepage.php?referer=http%3A%2F%2Fthisurl%2Fthispage.php");
```

that is, send the referer URL as a query string parameter, then you can access it as `$_GET['referer']`. This is probably more reliable than relying on the browser to send a referer header.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP Referer: header is set by the user agent, and not by the server. I'm not sure that there is anything you can do to ensure that you get a Referer header.